# mongodb .find().sort().limit(1).toArray() takes just as long as without .limit(1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to work through a performance issue in my app and I have a query which returns 835 rather large documents from mongo and calling the .toArray method on it takes almost a full second.

I really only need the record with the highest value so i'm trying to do a sort() and then a .limit() but when i do .toArray(), the performance is just as slow with the .limit(1) as it is without the .limit(1);

How can this be and how can I get around this issue?

I noticed that `.nextObject()` has no impact on the performance over `.toArray()` either.

```
var query = {
  "participation":{
    "$elemMatch":{
      "typeCode":"SBJ",
      "role.id":{
        "$elemMatch":{
          "root":"1.2.3.99.100",
          "extension":"123456"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "code.code":{
    "$in":["first","second"]
  }
};


console.time('performance');
data = mongoCollection
    .find(query)
    .sort({'effectiveTime.value':-1});

data.toArray(function (err, result) {
  console.log(result.length) => 835
  console.timeEnd('performance'); => Around 900ms
```

VS

```
var query = {
      "participation":{
        "$elemMatch":{
          "typeCode":"SBJ",
          "role.id":{
            "$elemMatch":{
              "root":"1.2.3.99.100",
              "extension":"123456"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "code.code":{
        "$in":["first","second"]
      }
    };
console.time('performance');
data = mongoCollection
    .find(query)
    .sort({'effectiveTime.value':-1}).limit(1);

data.toArray(function (err, result) {
  console.log(result.length) => 1
  console.timeEnd('performance'); => Around 900ms
```

Note: an easier way to read that query which produces the same results is:

```
var query {
        'participation.typeCode':'SBJ',
        'participation.role.id.root': '1.2.3.99.100', 
        'participation.role.id.extension': '123456'
    };
```

Note: The query itself runs fast in a mongo GUI client, without the sort on, but with the sort the query itself takes almost a full second.

Is there a better way to get the highest value of an attribute in a collection other than sort?

Comment: If the sort isn't able to take advantage of an index then all the docs needs to be read into memory regardless of `limit(1)`. Do you have an index that supports this combination of query and sort?

Comment: I added an index to 'effectiveTime.value' and it didn't seem to do anything for performance.

Comment: That index likely can't be used by the sort as the _combination_ of your query and sort must all be able to leverage the same index. Can you update your question with your `query` object?